# \@indexfile undefined

Tags: indexing

The csname `\@indexfile` is used in `source2e`, `makeidx`, `hyperref`, `amsidx` and various other sty files.  Yet every time I try to access it, it is undefined.  As you can see I am using `\makeindex` and `\makeatletter`.  What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{subindex}[page]
\renewcommand{\thesubindex}{\thepage\alph{subindex}}

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
  \refstepcounter{subindex}%
  \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
     {\string\indexentry{#1}{\thesubindex}}%
\endgroup\@esphack}% started by \index
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text and \index{indexed term}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works with `makeidx`. Traditional `\makeindex` defines the file handle `\@indexfile`, but the `imakeidx` version doesn't

Comment: imakeidx redefines `\makeindex` so you can't rely on the latex names.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not wedded to imakeidx.  Didn't even notice.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: You have changed the question by the comment -- the question was about `\@indexfile` not about whether `1a` is possible or not

Answer (score 4):

Since `imakeidx` allows for multiple index files, the file handle `\@indexfile` wouldn't be unique (I don't deal with the `splitindex` option here)

The relevant starter command is `\imki@startidxsplit`:

```
\def\imki@startidxsplit#1{%
\if@filesw
\def\index{\@bsphack
\@ifnextchar [{\@index}{\@index[\imki@jobname]}}
\expandafter\newwrite\csname #1@idxfile\endcsname
\immediate\openout \csname #1@idxfile\endcsname #1.idx\relax
\typeout{Writing index file #1.idx}%
\fi}
```

It will create a `\#1@idxfile` file handle, i.e. the file handle name  depends on the `name=#1` argument used in `\makeindex`.

If `\makeindex` is used without optional argument and `name=...` option, the index file handle is `\jobname@idxfile` then. (after expansion of `\jobname` of course) e.g. `\foo@idxfile`

Here's an excerpt of `imakeidx` documentation:

> name is the symbolic name for an index; if this key is not specified,
>   it defaults to the value of the \jobname control sequence, in other
>   words the name of the current main .tex file, i.e., the file that
>   \inputs and/or \includes all the files of the complete document. This
>   symbolic name is necessary only when doing multiple indices and is
>   used with the \index command to point to the right index.

Comment: If I had read the imakeidx manual, would any of this be needed?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I answered in the sense that you've got `imakeidx` included in your MWE right from the start. The culprit is that you assumed, `\@indexfile` is valid in any case -- it isn't. If you can live with `makeidx`, your example will do. If you need `imakeidx`, you have to provide the expanded filehandle to your `\@wrindex` macro  -- the question is, if you could not find another way round.